# No trackable performance differences between ReduceByKey and GroupByKey in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, shuffle

I am currently running an experiment in PySpark where I compare the overall performance of the wide transformations `reduceByKey` and `groupByKey`. I would expect to see a difference in performance (time execution) and in total records read and total records written between both (reduceByKey internall arquitecture reduces values locally before shuffling the data, so I would expect less data shuffling in this case). However, after running both experiments over datasets with increasing sizes, I can't see any differences, like shown in the table below.

[Shuffle Total Records Read and Total Records Writen groupByKey vs reduceByKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qO8Z.png)

I would expect the Shuffle Read Records and Shuffle Write Records to be different for reduceByKey and groupByKey for each data file.

The code of the transformations is the following:

```
def GroupByKey_1(conf_parameters, fp_file_input):
    sc = SparkContext_app_setup(conf_parameters)
    applicationId = sc.applicationId
    rdd_base = sc.textFile(fp_file_input)
    rdd_mapped = rdd_mapped.map(lambda x: (x[0], 1))
    rdd_group = rdd_mapped.groupByKey().mapValues(sum)
    print(f'El número de resgistros por estación es: {rdd_group.collect()}')
    sc.stop()
    process_logs(applicationId)
```

```
def ReduceByKey_1(conf_parameters, fp_file_input):
    sc = SparkContext_app_setup(conf_parameters)
    applicationId = sc.applicationId
    rdd_base = sc.textFile(fp_file_input)
    rdd_mapped = rdd_mapped.map(lambda x: (x[0], 1))
    rdd_reduce = rdd_mapped.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    print(f'El número de resgistros por estación es: {rdd_reduce.collect()}')
    sc.stop()
    process_logs(applicationId)
```

Why can't I see any differences in performance? Any help would be very much appreaciated. Thanks a lot in advance!